# Word 2007: Placing pictures inside table

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

In Word 2007, I tried to create a table of 10 columns and 1 row for placing 10 pictures. Knowing that the picture placeholders (picture content control) in Word 2007 cannot be used to align with text (the "Wrap Text" option is grayed in Word 2007 while it can work for picture content control in Word 2010), I inserted a small image in each cell instead, and then set the "Wrap Text" as "Square" and also "Align Center" and "Align Bottom". The upper part of the figure below shows what I got (the small image is shown as light blue rectangles, and xxx are the text which serve as image captions).

[image]

Next I tested the table by selecting the leftmost cell, right clicked and selected "Change Picture", and inserted a large picture (the egret). What I target to achieve is something like the middle part of the above figure: After some resizing, the whole egret bird image will be shown while the rightmost cells may go out of the margin or even the page boundary.

However, in reality, what I obtained was something like the lower part of the figure. Part of the egret picture (the rightmost portion) was "cut" (became invisible), and for each of the remaining cells, the rightmost part of the placeholder image is also "cut". The width of the table did not change.

I tried to modify the "Table Properties" and change the table's preferred width, and there are 3 different cases:

Case 1: Do not tick the "Preferred width" at all, and the table width seems to be bounded by the distance between the left and right margins (let's call it *d*).

Case 2: Tick the "Preferred width" and enter a width wider than *d*. In this case, the table width will be what I set, and if the pictures are small, some space will be left in each cell. If the pictures are large, the right side of each picture in the table are "cut".

Case 3: Tick the "Preferred width" and enter a width ≤ *d*. In Word 2007, the observation is same as Case 2 -- the right side of each picture in the table are "cut". But in Word 2010, this will result in what I want (the middle part of the above figure).

So, are there any settings (most probably on the tables) in Word 2007 that allows me to achieve what I want?